# What is this short plant with feathery red-tinged silver-green evergreen foliage and all-yellow flowers?

Tags: identification

20 cm high, 30 cm wide is this strange creature. Garden in continental part of Balkan peninsula, zone 7a. It looks to be a herbaceus but evergreen plant.

[image]

[image]

[image]

View from above:

[image]

[image]

Update: The plant grew rapidly to 40-50 cm, lost red color, flower buds appeared. Also, this is its second year. First year it was just tiny, a couple of short branches, no flowers.

Update 2: Flowers start appearing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update 3:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is amazing that the flowers in the middle form “sunflower pattern” (that was shown to have some connection to “golden ratio” in mathematics), however, these flowers are tiny, barely 3 cm/1 in radius.

Comment: I would go got a Tanacetum. I never see it so redish, but it is evergreen, and used in traditional cooking on spring. It is an Asteraceae (Compositae), so without flower (and detail of "fruits) we cannot identify precisely.

Comment: @Giacomo I added some pictures... What do you think?

Comment: You have pictures of some juniper and other pictures of a flowering plant; So two IDs ?

Comment: It is an Asteraceae, as I guessed last year. It is a difficult family. I need to check my books

Comment: @blacksmith37 the same plant is on all photos. the difference is time of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *Anthemis tinctoria*   Yellow Chamomile - just spent ages trying to find it online when I came across yours!